# Retrieving A Value From A Void Function

Tags: c, linux, unix

I was recently given an assignment by one of my professors in which I have to write a piece of code in which it prompts for a salary, years of service, and then based on those two pieces of info it calculates a bonus. I've worked with functions declared as doubles, but this is my first time working with void functions. I'm having trouble understanding how I can get my first function to save the prompted values for years of service and salary and then use those in the next function to calculate the bonus. This is what I currently have:

```
#include <cstdio>

void GetInput()
{
double salary;
int years_service;

printf("Enter your salary: ");
scanf("%lf", &salary);

printf("How many years have your served for us? ");
scanf("%d", &years_service);
}

void CalcRaise()
{
//I initialized salary and years_service because they would not compile 
//otherwise. As expected, it does run but since they are set to 0, the 
//bonus will be zero.

double salary = 0;
int years_service = 0;

double bonusA;
double bonusB;
double bonusC;

bonusA = salary * .02;
bonusB = salary * .05;
bonusC = salary * .10;

if ( years_service < 2)
{
    printf("Here is your bonus: %lf", bonusA);
}

else if ( years_service > 5 && years_service < 10)
{
    printf("Here is your bonus: %lf", bonusB);
}

else
{
    printf("Here is your bonus: %lf", bonusC);
}
return;
}


int main()
{

GetInput();
CalcRaise();

 return 0;
}
```

As I mentioned, I'm just having trouble figuring out how to save the values from my first function and use those to calculate the bonus. Any help is appreciated. -Thanks

Comment: Pass pointers to the first function (`GetInput()`).  Pass values to the second function (`CalcRaise()`).

Comment: I used the & to try and reference the variables but I was slightly confused on how to pass them to the function, as in where to put the syntax

Comment: Weird bonus scheme: those with 0 or 1 years' service get 2%; those with 6-9 years service get 5%, those with 2-5 years service and those with 10 or more years service get 10%.  Fortunately, it's only a classroom exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Make all the variables global, and initialize those variables in the starting stage itself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double salary = 0;
int years_service = 0;
double bonusA;
double bonusB;
double bonusC;

void GetInput()
{
    printf("Enter your salary: ");
    scanf("%lf", &salary);
    printf("How many years have your served for us? ");
    scanf("%d", &years_service);
}

void CalcRaise()
{
    bonusA = salary * .02;
    bonusB = salary * .05;
    bonusC = salary * .10;
    if (years_service < 2)
    {
        printf("Here is your bonus: %lf", bonusA);
    }
    else if (years_service > 5 && years_service < 10)
    {
        printf("Here is your bonus: %lf", bonusB);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Here is your bonus: %lf", bonusC);
    }
}

int main()
{  
    GetInput();
    CalcRaise();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I always seem to overlook the simplest solutions. Thank you

Comment: Global variables are generally not a good idea.  They are easily avoided here, and should be avoided here.

Comment: Just for beginner level, that's enough